# Xamarin Forms App with Rg.Plugins.Popup crashes on Android device

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, popupwindow

I have created an app. I have used the `Rg.Plugins.Popup` plugin from `nuget` package manager to show Custom Popups. In **Debug** version, the app works fine on Android devices. But in **release** mode, when I try to open the popup it crashes on my Moto G4,  Moto G6, and LGE LG-H872 Android device.

I am opening the popup using the following.

**My code**

```
NavigationParameters oNavParams = new NavigationParameters();
oNavParams.Add("Mode", "MainPageLocation");
oNavParams.Add("selectedItem", Value);
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MyrgModal", oNavParams);
```

After opening the popup it just gets stuck and crashes. I am not able to find the reason for the crash.

**Details:**

```
Rg.Plugins.Popup-1.1.4.168
Xamarin.Forms-2.5.0.280555
Android OS-7.0 and 8.0
Device Model-Moto G4, Moto G6, and LGE LG-H872
```

Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: I think It has nothing to do with popup plugin, it's due to the release configuration how is it, can you provide us the logcat log ?

Comment: @toumir This is the device log I get every time I try to open the modal:-                  Time                           Device Name         Type PID Tag Message
09-03 14:40:44.663 Motorola moto g(6) Error 571 ANDR-PERF-MPCTL Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only

Comment: this is how to get the log information(vs 2017): View -> Other Windows -> Device Log, Tools -> Android -> Device Log, run the app, click the button to open the popup window, after that send us the log content

Comment: another resource to get the logcat :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=vswin

Comment: I was able to get it working.Check this link (https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/issues/364)